# Double derivation - why cast is necessary

Tags: c++, inheritance

The following code contains several header files in which classes are defined: 
`area, circle, ring, rectangle, pattern`. `area` is the basis class, circle is a derivation. `ring` and `rectangle` are derivations of `circle` and `pattern` is a derivation of both `circle` and `rectangle`, describing a geometrical figure of a coloured circle, which contains a rectangle shaped hole. The class `area` defines a variable `color` which due to the double derivation will be contained in `pattern` twice. Anyways, I hope I can state this question in a way that you can follow along!

Consider this code:

```
int main() {
    area *list[8];
    ring blue_ring("BLUE",5,2);
    pattern blue_pattern("BLUE",30,5,5);
    list[0]=&blue_ring;
    list[4]=static_cast<circle *>(&blue_pattern);
    return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is the cast in the third last line. The object `blue_pattern` is of the type `pattern`. Well and the pointer array `list` stores addresses pointing to objects of the type `area`. So why do I have to convert `blue_pattern` to an object of type `circle`. 
This is an example from a programming beginners book. It says in there that the cast is necessary because the object `pattern` contains data from `area` twice. But I don't understand this reasoning.

Here's me trying to provide minimal code, which is just the headers:

"example0051.h"

```
#ifndef _AREA_
#define _AREA_
class area {
public: 
    area(char * n);
    ~area();
    void getColor() const;
private: 
    char color[11];
};

#endif
```

"example0052.h"

```
#ifndef _CIRCLE_
#define _CIRCLE_
#include "example0051.h"

class circle : public area {
public: 
    circle(char * n, float a);
    ~circle();

    float calculateArea() const;
private: 
    float radius;
};

#endif
```

"example0054.h"

```
#ifndef _RECTANGLE_
#define _RECTANGLE_
#include "example0051.h"

class rectangle : public area {
public: 
    rectangle(char * n, float a, float b);
    ~rectangle();
    float calculateArea() const;
private:
    float length;
    float width;
};

#endif
```

"example0055.h"

```
#ifndef _PATTERN_
#define _PATTERN_
#include "example0052.h"  // circle
#include "example0054.h" // rectangle

class pattern : public circle, public rectangle {
public: pattern(char * n, float a, float b, float c);
        ~pattern();
        float calculateArea() const;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Instead of only describing your classes and their possible inheritance hierarchy, please try to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: you don't need to post the whole headers. Please don't do this. But you do need to create a [mcve]. In your case this probably means just the definitions of all the classes, **with an empty body**. Just so that it compiles and shows your problem.

Comment: Is `blue_pattern` really a child class of `circle`? Bet you a quid it ain't.

Comment: there is a class that inherits from both `circle` and `rectangle`? *Independence day* ain't got nothing on you.

Comment: A beginners' book that teaches misdesigned class hierarchies and then proceeds to hack around that broken design doesn't sound like a good source to learn from.

Comment: If you *don't* have the cast, what problems do you get? What does the compiler tell you?

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't use symbols with a leading underscore followed by an upper-case letter (like e.g. `_AREA_`), those are reserved. Please see [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for more details.

Comment: `#define _AREA_`, `_RECTANGLE_`, `_PATTERN_`. Those symbols are reserved to the implementation and defining them has undefined behaviour.

Comment: IMO, `pattern` should inherit from `area` and have `circle` and `rectangle` members.

Comment: I strongly suggest you find a better book. Pretty much any book on the topic is going to better than that. A pattern is a round rectangle which is an area twice over and you can calculate the area of either of those areas so the pattern has 2 areas as well as being 2 areas? Its going to be very hard to learn the concept from such a bad design.

Comment: apparently the book isn't the best. It is very light however, just intended as starting literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note how your hierarchy looks like:

```
  area        area
   ^           ^
   |           |
   |           |
rectangle    circle
   ^           ^
    \         /
     \       /
      \     /
      pattern
```

So `pattern *` can be cast to `area *` in two ways.
Compiler can't decide by itself which version is more valid so it will print an error.

When casting to `circle *` is added it is clear how to perform conversion to `area *`.

Probably in next step you will learn about virtual inheritance and diamond problem, but in my opinion this example is terrible and this should be resolved by composition, not by multiple inheritance.

Comment: thx Marek, you're right btw, virtual inheritance is next... so when I cast `blue_pattern` to `circle` my object is of type `circle` now. In both classes I have defined a function `calculateArea()` and I still want to calculate the area of the pattern and not the circle. Will this work?